# TFS 2012 Burndown Chart Not Updating

Tags: tfs

I've got some problems with my TFS Burndown Chart. I've just created an Iteration (Sprint) with no start - end date. Then added some Working Items - Tasks each with their corresponding start - end date (lets say 10/06/2014). 6 days have passed since I realized that my whole Iteration (Sprint) did not have start - ending dates (10/06/2014 - 27/06/2014), so I've added those, but now... my Burndown chart is showing the progress only from dates 16/06/2014 to the current date, up to the finish date: 27/06/2014

Most of My Working Items (tasks) inside the Iteration - Sprint have their Start, In Progress and Finished within the current dates: 10/06/2014 - 16/06/2014.

Please Advice.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how your tasks have starting/ending dates.  I thought all the default templates had Work Remaining on Tasks.  Anyways, the burndown operates off the Work Remaining fields of the Tasks, you need to update that appropriately.

Answer (score 0):

You should set start and end dates for the sprints themselves.  Without start/end dates for the sprint itself, it can't project how much time you have left given the total task work at the beginning of the sprint.  An iteration path (i.e. sprint) is inherently a period of time for doing your work (i.e. 2-4 weeks).